# xCode iOS Dev - ld: library not found for -lzbar

Tags: ios, xcode, linker

Good Afternoon Folks!  I have gotten my iOS App (written in xCode) down to 1 warning & 1 error.  My error is:
**ld: library not found for -lzbar
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

If anyone is feeling up to it, Please have a look & let me know if you see the simple problem.  I realize that it is missing a linker file.  I can not locate it, & reapplying all documents within this project to a new project does not solve the issue.

Does anyone mind helping me out?  Thank you very much.
I have attempted to Google answers for this issue relentlessly before posting this.
Somehow I couldn't find a concise answer, as to what my problem was.

Thank you towards anyone willing to help!

---

```
Ld /Users/PsychodelicFuzz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CHH-bmbqxvfwddzaupfaavvipxaqwvfx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CHH.app/CHH normal i386
cd "/Users/PsychodelicFuzz/Desktop/Hospital App"
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/PsychodelicFuzz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CHH-bmbqxvfwddzaupfaavvipxaqwvfx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/PsychodelicFuzz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CHH-bmbqxvfwddzaupfaavvipxaqwvfx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/PsychodelicFuzz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CHH-bmbqxvfwddzaupfaavvipxaqwvfx/Build/Intermediates/CHH.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CHH.build/Objects-normal/i386/CHH.LinkFileList -dead_strip -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreMedia -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreVideo -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -lzbar -o /Users/PsychodelicFuzz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CHH-bmbqxvfwddzaupfaavvipxaqwvfx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CHH.app/CHH
```

ld: library not found for -lzbar
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You are going to need to know what libzbar.a is and what it provides, which isn't unreasonable given you are linking it with your app.  If you can get the source then you can compile the library yourself, else you'll need to get a `.a` from someone else...

Comment: my libzbar.a file is within my xcode project.  I must have incorrectly applied it to my application.  I see that it is my error, but how do I replace it, if it is already available within my application?  (thanks for the speedy reply, btw)

Comment: If you need it, then you haven't configured it correctly (the linker cannot find it).  If you don't need it, then remove any reference to it from within Xcode.

Comment: sorry if this is a NOOB question...
but How would I go about removing the reference?

Comment: It will appear in: Project > Summary > Linked Frameworks and Libraries.  Also possibly in Project > Build Settings > Other Linker Flags.

Comment: These Recommendations Did Not Solve The Problem. :(  Any other suggestions?  I have been stuck on this 1 error for multiple days.  I am getting so frustrated, I'm thinking about giving up.

Comment: You need to look around and find it; it's there somewhere.  Giving up is for quitters!